# Django / an argument with HttpResponseRedirect is empty in my HTML page

Tags: django

In Views.py

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('add_scenes?submitted=True?linkToPrevScene=%s'%ScenePrevious)
```

ScenePrevious is a string containing "water2"

In my URL of add_scenes.html it works :

*http://127.0.0.1:8000/scenes3d/add_scenes?submitted=True?linkToPrevScene=water2*

But in the file add_scenes.html

```
   {% if submitted %}
        your scene was submitted successfully after {{ linkToPrevScene }} 
   {% else %}
```

this HTML code doesn't give output for {{ linkToPrevScene }} although  {% if submitted %} is evaluated correctly

**edit of my post:**
This line also doesn't work if I replace the second ? by &

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('add_scenes?submitted=True&linkToPrevScene=%s'%ScenePrevious)
```

Comment: Query parameters are not automatically added to the template context. You have to do that explicitly in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't comment but you need to pass the parameter `linkToPrevScene` through the view for you to receive it in the template.
**Note:**In Django You can not pass parameters with redirect. Your only bet is to pass them as a part of URL.

```
    #...Rest of your view...
    context['linkToPrevScene'] = Water2

    redirect(reverse('add_scenes?submitted=True?linkToPrevScene=%s'%ScenePrevious, kwargs={ 'linkToPrevScene': Water2 }))
```

Use the links below for reference
Django documentaion:

- [Reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)
- [Redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)